# Rails - How to implement :remote => true, to edit comments on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm building an events site using Rails 5. On the Event#show page I have a comments section which I want to give edit/update functionality to without the user leaving the page. 
I'm trying to use `:remote => true` in the form but I'm hitting errors, here's the views and controller code -

**comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @event.comments.build, :remote => true ]) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
def update

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.js   { }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The current error I'm getting is 'undefined method `model_name' for {:remote=>true}:Hash'. This is pointing to the events#show method in the Events controller. I'm not sure I'm using :remote => true in the correct place hence the error. This is the first time I've done this so I'm hitting errors each step of the way. Any help/assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: try moving `:remote => true` outside the array: `simple_form_for([@event, @event.comments.build], remote: true)`

Comment: Thanks, this has removed the error but the page won't allow me to update the comment. Do I need to include a js.erb file?

Comment: `@event.comments.build` builds the structure of a new `comment`, that new(not yet saved) object is used in the form `f` to build the whole form html structure. Short answer, that form must be pointing to the `create` and not the `update`, why ?, as I told you `@event.comments.build` builds a new `comment` which is not yet saved.

Comment: So, what do i change the hash to? Or do i adjust the create method in the controller?

Comment: what does the rails console show you when you click on `Add Comment`, is the request going to  the `create` action ?, it should go there; so, if you don't have a `create` action add it, and you'll have to adapt your code so that it creates a new `comment` with the given parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using proper format of `simple_form_for`. It should be

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @event.comments.build], remote: true ) do |f| %>
```